# Compose sequences with multicharacter result don't work

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, compose-key

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I set compose key on CapsLock.

It seems some specific compose key combinations don't work at all. For example, typing Compose+'+j does totally nothing. This combination should be easy to reproduce on most keyboards, corresponding string from the Compose file:

```
<Multi_key> <apostrophe> <j>        : "j́"    # LATIN SMALL LETTER J U006A with COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT U0301
```

Note that this combination results in two characters, unlike most other combinations which seem to work fine. I'm not sure whether it's X bug or Unity bug.

Answer (score 0):

To access all the characters in `en_US.UTF-8/Compose`, you need to enable XIM as input method (can be done from *System Settings -> Language Support*) and relogin (or possibly reboot).

Please note that XIM does not work on Wayland - can't tell if it's a bug or intentionally - so for Ubuntu 17.10 you need to log in to an "Ubuntu on Xorg" session.

Comment: a potentially unwanted side effect of enabling XIM in GTK apps is that it disables the `ctrl+shift+u` method for entering an arbitrary unicode point ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg#Configuring_compose_key)).

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that using XIM also creates more problems. Likewise, it seems impossible to use CJK IME anymore.

Comment: @IvanG.: Indeed you need to have e.g. IBus or Fcitx enabled for CJK input methods, and that precludes the use of XIM concurrently.

Comment: @quixotic Wow, that is terrible. Assuming it actually worked for me, this would make XIM unusable for me. And then there are also supposed to be other bugs...